# Javascript From Console - Load a Few Pages, Then Run Function Per Page Load

Tags: javascript, html

This is not a copy of another question, or at least, I did not find a similar one.

I have a few pages, and I want to periodically run a script from my Chrome's console, that visits a page, once it's loaded, look for something in the page's contents.

Problem is, it does not even run the function when it does.
Here's a simple example.

```
window.location.replace('http://www.google.com/');
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
alert("Page loaded!");
}, false);
```

I've tried other types of course, such as window.onload, or document.onload.

Other solutions speak of scripts that are embedded in the html page itself.

As an extra, is there a way to get a page's content without even opening the page in the browser? Just get the page's html content?

I am sure it can be done via other languages, but I want a quick solution right now.

Thanks in advance!